# Wordpress admin menu always show sub menus

Tags: wordpress, dashboard, submenu

Wordpress admin menu always show sub menus. (I mean, this submenus are always open) And it started when I had more than 345 custom post types. Every new custom post type which I add, starts showing new sub menus.

If I have less custom post types, everything is OK.

[It looks like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ad20Y.jpg)

UPDATE:

```
/**
 * Register post type XXX.
 */
add_action( 'init', 'create_post_type_XXX' );
function create_post_type_XXX() {
  register_post_type( 'XXX',
    array(
      'labels' => array(
        'name' => __( 'XXX ),
        'singular_name' => __( 'XXX' )
      ),
      'supports' => array ('title','editor','thumbnail','post-formats','comments'),
      'public' => true,
      'has_archive' => true,
    )
  );
}
```

Comment: You have 345 custom post-types?  How are you creating these custom post-types?  There's possibly an issue with the process.

Comment: I use register post type. Below you can see code.

Comment: I added the code from your 'answer' to your question - if you're adding more information add it to the original question so as to prevent the whole thread from becoming confusing.  345 CPTs is a lot... ....regardless, are there any errors in your console log?  This sounds likes its more of a js issue than a specific PHP/CPT issue.

Comment: In console isn't any problem.
I  see this sub menu because there is property Top: -1000em for #adminmenu .wp-submenu. When i change them for example to -1200em, this sub-menu of course disappear, but after that dont work sub-menu when i clicked on first level menu.

It looks like, standard wordpress admin works max for Top: -1000em and after i add a lots of post-types, this ruined this property, becouse screen is too "long"

Comment: Why do you have 345 custom post types? I'm guessing that is causing WP some confusion with displaying the menu information.

Comment: I think custom taxonomies for your custom post types may reduce the number of your post types, and could make a improvement to the usability of your backend. It will not be a solution to your actual problem but maybe this way you can ship around, I also don't thing wordpress admin menu was made for handling this huge number of menu items.

Comment: disinfor: every brand what I have, is post type. And now I have more than 300 brands :D rank: I tried change name of post types to shortest version, but this is stil not enough. For now I have just two solutions. Change property Top to bigger number. Or changge Position: absolute to relative. I just dont understand how this property Top:1000em work. If you have 5 post types everything works, if you have 200 post types it works too. I mean this number isnt flexibile. Always it is 1000em. And i dont understand why, when i change this property hover effect for sub-menus dont work.....

Comment: There must be another property, which is related to "Top: 1000 em", but I don't see them.

Comment: Or third solution is somehow customize menu. All brands that starts "A" will be under "A-brands" menu. This A-brands menu must work like folder. But I think this is not possible to make in Wordpress.